# How to transpose a 2D-list into a column view?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this 2D-list

```
[["a1", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"]]
```

That I want to transpose to a column-view.
Each inner list has the same size.

Expected result :

```
[['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2']]
```

I'm looking for a one-liner answer.

I've tried the code below that works but needs one line to initialize the `l_col` variable and two for the loop.

```py
l = [["a1", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"]]

l_col = []
for i in range(len(l[0])):
    l_col.append([x[i] for x in l])

print(l_col)  # [['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2']]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[x[i] for x in l] for i in range(len(l[0]))]
```

Comment: perhaps the most unpythonic answer possible.

Comment: @gog are list comprehensions unpythonic?

Comment: LC's are fine, `range(len)` and nested loops are not.

Comment: you wrote the most `unpythonic answer`. `range(len)` are also from python. I know enumerate but, I didn't modify OP's code to make them comfortable, I just adjusted it to make it a one-liner

Comment: in fact at the beginning I also wanted to avoid `range(len)`.
but I found what I've written with `enumerate` was worse : `for i, _ in enumerate(l[0])`

Comment: "unpythonic" means "not idiomatic in python". `for x in lst` is idiomatic, `for i in range(len(lst))` is not. But the most unpythonic part is that you're reinventing the wheel instead of using a built-in.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Python, you can use:

```
A           = [["a1", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"]]
A_transpose = list(map(list,zip(*A)))

print('A_transpose: ', A_transpose)

# output:
#     A_transpose:  [['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2']]
```

---

PS. For many applications, `list(zip(*A))` also works. However, this short command returns tuples in the inner dimension: `[('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2'), ('c1', 'c2')]`. In the code above, we corrected this issue by introducing `map(list,...)`.

Comment: `list(map(list` is not particularly readable, I'd use `[list(p) for p in zip(*a)]`, if the OP really needs lists and `list(zip(*a))` otherwise.